# Tika: how to enable the debug output?

Tags: logging, apache-tika

I was parsing Office documents with Tika without problems until yesterday. The programs hangs here:

```
InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(new File(sourceUrl));
ContentHandler content = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
LinkContentHandler links = new LinkContentHandler();
ContentHandler handler = new TeeContentHandler(links, content);
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
parser.parse(input,handler,metadata,context); // HANGS HERE!
```

How can I enable the debug output? Could that help me find the cause.

**Edit:** it looks like the answer is more complex than I think... http://wiki.apache.org/tika/Logging

Comment: If you force a JVM thread dump once the hang has occurred, what does that show the process blocked on doing?

Comment: @Gagravarr  Thank you for the advice, but I changed Tika for a simpler library using this code ==> https://codezrule.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/extract-text-from-pdf-office-files-doc-ppt-xls-open-office-files-rtf-and-textplain-files-in-java/   I modified it using the last POI libraries, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: That uses ancient versions of the various libraries - the POI version used is over 10 years old! Oh so many bug fixes and new features missed :( I'd really suggest trying Tika again, and dumping the JVM thread stack when it hangs

Comment: I was very easy update it to the last POI version. A little of Maven, other little of use the "extractor" classes and it was done :-)  I will upload it to my GitHub account.

Comment: Uploaded ==> https://github.com/mariosotil/text-extractor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of file you are extracting. Tika uses many third party libraries, which in turn use different logging frameworks.

For example,
pdfbox uses log4j
poi uses custom logging.

For pdfbox it straight-forward. Just create a log4j.properties and set the pdfbox package to log in DEBUG.

For poi, you have to do more. Enable apache-commons logging, and set the POILogger to CommonLogger,

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.util.POILogger", "org.apache.poi.util.CommonsLogger" );
```

Here is how my log4j.properties looks like,

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.file.File=log/filecrawler.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, stdout

# for pdfbox
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font=DEBUG
```